# Get request URL from grails controller

Tags: controller, url-mapping, querystringparameter

My grails controller gets invoked by the following URLs

```
/center/madrid/12-de-octubre
/center/madrid/12-de-octubre?opt=1
```

I need the controller to behave differently if there are any parameters after the ? in the URL

I have the following URL mapping:

```
   name center: "/center/$_uni_city/$_uni_facility_name" {
        controller = "site"
        action = "centerprofile"
}
```

While I can find all parameters (e.g. _uni_city=Madrid, opt=1) I am unable to determine which parameters come from the querystring after applying URLMappings (i.e. opt in the example above).

Is there a way to retrieve the original request URL (i.e.
/center/madrid/12-de-octubre?opt=1) in the grails controller?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get the original parameters in the request URL use:

```
request.queryString
```

Comment: Thanks.

This property is not even mentioned on the Grails doc, this is lame.

Comment: @Ser well, the docs do mention that `request` is an implementation of `HttpServletRequest`, which `getQueryString()` is part of.  http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html

Answer (score 5):

See description of [Grails request](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Servlet%20API/request.html).

- **forwardURI** - Useful for obtaining the current request URI since the
  request objects requestURI property returns the original URI, not the
  matched one.

Solution:

```
class URLController{
  def printCurrentUrl = {
   render request.forwardURI
  }
}
```

Comment: Does this retrieves the domain? ... i mean ... the entire URL?